# Manual bootstrapping and Data Sharing in b/w controllers through angular service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

- I am trying to share data in b/w controllers through angular service. 
  It worked perfectly fine if i let my app to bootrap automatically.
- But when i manually bootstrap part of my HTML with same app, Data sharing between controllers do not work as expected.

Attached herewith is the fiddle and plnckr.

[plnckr with auto bootstrap](http://plnkr.co/edit/rQvzjfB0YO4peulimivc?p=preview)

[plnckr with manual bootstrap](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxgPzeTFOWmkXGnv1lAK?p=preview)

**Following is the working code of data sharing b/w controllers through service/factory using auto bootstrap**

```js
// Code goes here

// Code goes here

// Code goes here

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.factory('MyFactory', function() {
    var myFactory = {};
    
    myFactory.myProperty = {prop: 'Hello'};
    myFactory.setProperty = function(value) {
      this.myProperty.prop = value;
    };
    return myFactory;
  });

  app.service('MyService', function() {
    this.myProperty = {prop: 'Test'};
    this.setProperty = function(value) {
      this.myProperty.prop = value;
    }
  });

  app.controller('DummyController', DummyController);
  DummyController.$Inject = ['$scope', 'MyFactory', 'MyService'];

  app.controller('Dummy1Controller', Dummy1Controller);
  Dummy1Controller.$Inject = ['$scope', 'MyFactory', 'MyService'];



  function DummyController($scope, MyFactory, MyService) {
    $scope.property = MyFactory.myProperty;
    $scope.property1 = MyService.myProperty;

  }

  function Dummy1Controller($scope, MyFactory, MyService) {
    MyFactory.setProperty('World1144');
    $scope.property = MyFactory.myProperty;

    MyService.setProperty('World1144');
    $scope.property1 = MyService.myProperty;
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='myApp'>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Example [As a Service]</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div ng-controller='DummyController' class='col-md-6'>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  DummyController
                  <div>
                    Current Factory Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property.prop'>
                    <br> Current Service Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property1.prop'>

                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div ng-controller='Dummy1Controller' class='col-md-6'>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  Dummy1Controller
                  <div>
                    Current Factory Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property.prop'>
                    <br> Current Service Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property1.prop'>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Following is the code of data sharing b/w controllers through service using manual bootstrap**

```js
// Code goes here

// Code goes here

// Code goes here

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.factory('MyFactory', function() {
    var myFactory = {};
    
    myFactory.myProperty = {prop: 'Hello'};
    myFactory.setProperty = function(value) {
      this.myProperty.prop = value;
    };
    return myFactory;
  });

  app.service('MyService', function() {
    this.myProperty = {prop: 'Test'};
    this.setProperty = function(value) {
      this.myProperty.prop = value;
    }
  });

  app.controller('DummyController', DummyController);
  DummyController.$Inject = ['$scope', 'MyFactory', 'MyService'];

  app.controller('Dummy1Controller', Dummy1Controller);
  Dummy1Controller.$Inject = ['$scope', 'MyFactory', 'MyService'];



  function DummyController($scope, MyFactory, MyService) {
    $scope.property = MyFactory.myProperty;
    $scope.property1 = MyService.myProperty;

  }

  function Dummy1Controller($scope, MyFactory, MyService) {
    MyFactory.setProperty('World1144');
    $scope.property = MyFactory.myProperty;

    MyService.setProperty('World1144');
    $scope.property1 = MyService.myProperty;
  }

  
})();

setTimeout(function(){ 
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector(".c1"), ["myApp"])//manual bootstrapping of PaginationComp
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector(".c2"), ["myApp"])
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body >
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Example [As a Service]</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div ng-controller='DummyController' class='col-md-6 c1'>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  DummyController
                  <div>
                    Current Factory Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property.prop'>
                    <br> Current Service Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property1.prop'>

                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div ng-controller='Dummy1Controller' class='col-md-6 c2'>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  Dummy1Controller
                  <div>
                    Current Factory Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property.prop'>
                    <br> Current Service Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property1.prop'>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out AngularJS Bootstraping guidelines here

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

When doing this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector(".c1"), ["myApp"])//manual bootstrapping of PaginationComp
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector(".c2"), ["myApp"])
}, 1000);
```

[You have more than one AngularJS application instance on your page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#things-to-keep-in-mind) and that is why the data is not shared between your controllers, since this service instances are living in different apps.

All you have to do is just to bootstrap the app once using the element that contains your [`ngController` directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController), for example:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector(".panel-body"), ["myApp"])
}, 1000);
```

Working fiddle:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.factory('MyFactory', function() {
    var myFactory = {};
    
    myFactory.myProperty = {prop: 'Hello'};
    myFactory.setProperty = function(value) {
      this.myProperty.prop = value;
    };
    return myFactory;
  });

  app.service('MyService', function() {
    this.myProperty = {prop: 'Test'};
    this.setProperty = function(value) {
      this.myProperty.prop = value;
    }
  });

  app.controller('DummyController', DummyController);
  DummyController.$Inject = ['$scope', 'MyFactory', 'MyService'];

  app.controller('Dummy1Controller', Dummy1Controller);
  Dummy1Controller.$Inject = ['$scope', 'MyFactory', 'MyService'];



  function DummyController($scope, MyFactory, MyService) {
    $scope.property = MyFactory.myProperty;
    $scope.property1 = MyService.myProperty;

  }

  function Dummy1Controller($scope, MyFactory, MyService) {
    MyFactory.setProperty('World1144');
    $scope.property = MyFactory.myProperty;

    MyService.setProperty('World1144');
    $scope.property1 = MyService.myProperty;
  }

  
})();

setTimeout(function(){ 
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector(".panel-body"), ["myApp"])
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Example [As a Service]</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div ng-controller='DummyController' class='col-md-6 c1'>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  DummyController
                  <div>
                    Current Factory Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property.prop'>
                    <br> Current Service Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property1.prop'>

                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div ng-controller='Dummy1Controller' class='col-md-6 c2'>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  Dummy1Controller
                  <div>
                    Current Factory Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property.prop'>
                    <br> Current Service Value :
                    <input type='text' ng-model='property1.prop'>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```